# CSS to create an acute isosceles triangle with curved edges

Tags: css, geometry, css-shapes

I am trying to create a triangle using purely CSS which has curved edges.

Is this possible without it being totally over the top?

I've added an example below of what I'm trying to achieve (the curved lines - not the straight lines).

[image: acute isosceles triangle with curved edges]

So far I have been working with the following code but it's not quite what I'm looking for.

```css
    #inner {
      transform: rotate(45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
      background-color: silver;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      top: 20px;
      left: -50px;
      position: relative;
      -moz-border-radius: 20px;
      border-radius: 20px;
    }
    #outer {
      position: absolute;
      width: 70px;
      height: 140px;
      top: 20px;
      left: 50px;
      overflow: hidden;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not saying it is impossible mate but for complex shapes like this one, CSS is not the best option. SVG or images would be a better fit (but then there is nothing wrong in trying though :))

Comment: @Harry Check my answer, shapes like this are not overly hard to create. You just need to know how :)

Comment: @Harry: I'd agree, svg seems perfect for this. The 'border radius' doesn't quite seem right for this for some reason :L

Comment: @Ruddy: I wasn't saying its not possible mate. With effort even more complex shapes are possible but at what expense? It takes quite a lot of effort to create such complex  shapes, position them such that they look same on all browsers, all zoom levels etc whereas the same could be achieved by other methods relatively quicker. That is all that I was trying to say.

Comment: @Harry Oh I didn't mean to say it that you said wasn't possible. I was just saying that the shape can be made without to much effort, just a lot of tweaking a fairly simple CSS shape. SVG would be better for this type of thing yes, I agree with that.

Comment: @Tom does it have to have the middle triangle or is that to be left out?

Comment: Thanks @ThePragmatick - there's a lot of answers to this and I'm working my way through them all to try and see which is going to be best for me.

Answer (score 4):

How about an `svg` solution?

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="-2 0 252 212">
  <path fill="rosybrown" d="M125 0 c-81.6 60 -113.3 130 -125 200 c83.3 40 166.6 40 250 0 c-11.7 -70 -43.4 -140 -125 -200" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="black" />
</svg>
```

Comment: thought you'd pop your head in at some point :) I knew svg would be the 'answer', just not how to do it :P

Answer (score 3):

Just another posibility, without using any rotation. Just clipping different circles.

```css
.triangle {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: lightblue;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.triangle div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 31%;
    left: 16%;
    background-color: lightyellow;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.triangle div:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    right: 30%;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle">
<div></div>
</div>
```

The light colors are there just to make the construction of the triangle more visible

Comment: Nice solution! Btw, **each vertex is the center of the opposite arc.**

Answer (score 2):

## solution 1: Using two elements

The first example is not perfect, but does sort of answers your question:

```css
.wrapper{
  /*overflow:hidden;*/
  width:0;
  border-top:100px solid transparent;
  border-left:100px solid red;
  position:relative;
  margin:50px;
  transform:rotate(135deg);
  }

.triangle{
  width:20px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  border-radius:50%;
  transform:translate(-110px);
  position:absolute;
  top:-100px;
  left:0;
  }
.triangle:after{
  content:"";
  width:100px;
  height:20px;
  background:red;
  border-radius:50%;
  transform:translate(0px);
  position:absolute;
  top:90px;
  left:10px;
  }
.triangle:before{
  content:"";
  width:140px;
  height:20px;
  background:red;
  border-radius:50%;
  transform:rotate(225deg);
  position:absolute;
  top:40px;
  left:-10px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
```

**Please note** This isn't an equilateral triangle, more of an isosceles one and could be edited into a better one no doubt!!

---

## Solution 2: Using a single element

I was trying to create this shape using a single `div` element, but i was only able to generate two sides of the triangle. So, from this, I deduced that using css along requires *two elements*:

Two sides Of the Triangle Shown:

```css
div {
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 126px solid blue;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  border-radius:50%;
  position: relative;
}
div:after,
div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 130px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: -15px;
    background: blue;
}
div:after {  
  left: -50px;
  transform: rotate(40deg);
}
div:before {
  left: 30px;
  transform: rotate(-40deg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

I am guessing that svg may be a better option (*note: I do not know svg, that seems like @chipChocolate.pys's area of expertise*). So using 'just pseudo effects', I think you're looking to use two elements (but I'd like to see be proved wrong!). The 'single element' doesn't *quite* seem right, but may or may not be perfect for you

Comment: Check out my answer, same idea just a lot closer to the finished look.

Answer (score 2):

### Pure CSS

Using different transforms.

I created three sectors using `transform: rotate(30deg);` and `transform-origin: 0% 100%;` Then I transformed their parent containers (`scaleX: -1;` for the left side). Done.

This can be done with just one pair of `#cont` and `#circ` elements, but I used different tags just for demonstrating better.

```css
#cont {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:relative;
}
#circ {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 0 300px 0 0;
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}
#cont:nth-of-type(2){
    top: -300px;
    transform: scaleX(-1);
}
#cont:nth-of-type(3){
    top: -600px;
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}
#cont:nth-of-type(3) > #circ {
    border-radius: 0 0 300px 0;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
    <div id="circ">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="cont">
    <div id="circ">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="cont">
    <div id="circ">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** For a real website, almost always use SVG. But creating shapes with CSS is an art which mustn't be killed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt at this. I think this is the best way to do it, using 1 element and `:before` `:after`.

Using the `div` as the base element (the bottom) we can line up the other 2 above it keeping the size and shape equal.

```css
div {
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px;
}
div:before, div:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 120px;
  top: -70px;
}
div:before {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  left: 8px;
}
div:after {
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
  right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

**Edit:**

Another Attempt, slight tweaking from the first.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 70px;
  margin: 100px;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 36px;
  height: 106px;
  top: -65px;
}
div:before {
  transform: rotate(28deg);
  left: 8px;
  border-right: 10px solid red;
}
div:after {
  transform: rotate(-28deg);
  right: 8px;
  border-left: 9px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Appreciate the effort though it is not yet exactly the same as what OP needs.

Answer (score 0):

I like the challenge :)

I recently have come to love the more complex border radius variations. I'm sure with some more fiddling and decent math calculations you can get rid of the rough edges where the different sides meet. No time for it now unfortunately.

```css
.triangle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 40px solid blue;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 80px 70px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(160deg);
}
.triangle:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 40px solid CornflowerBlue;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  left: -54px;
  top: -12px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 80px 70px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(120deg);
}
.triangle:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 40px solid darkblue;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  top: -30px;
  left: -29px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 80px 70px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(240deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```